# Why this Hierarchical Query don't work?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hierarchy

Given:

```
| ID_Composite1 | ID_Composite2 | DateStart | DateEnd   |
| 1             | 2             | 11-24-2015| 03-11-2016|
| 2             | 4             | 8-11-2015 | 12-11-2015|
```

I need to get:

```
| ID_Composite1 | ID_Composite2 | Month     |
| 1             | 2             | 11-24-2015|
| 1             | 2             | 12-24-2015|
| 1             | 2             |  1-24-2016|
| 1             | 2             |  2-24-2016|
| 1             | 2             |  3-11-2016|
| 2             | 4             | 8-11-2015 |
| 2             | 4             | 9-11-2015 |
| 2             | 4             | 9-11-2015 |
```

I tried the most simplified case (generate a range between only months using level and connect by) but I can't get it working:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1f45/3/0)

Comment: Do you want to get the Month from Date Start or Date End?

Comment: @Walucas yes, from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

So, I forced an iterator on your SQL, to make sure there will be enough rows to make things work properly....

check it out:

```
    SELECT firstcompositekey, secondcompositekey, to_char(add_months(startmonth, iterator),'MM-YYYY') as month
 FROM test, 
   (SELECT LEVEL iterator FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000) iterations
WHERE add_months(startmonth, iterator) <= endmonth
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1f45/21)

Hope this helps